# Не получается загрузить файлы

Tags: javascript, ajax-load

я хотел бы загрузить файлы на сервер через ajax, но когда загружается один файл, а следом тут же второй, то в последнем отображается прогресс файла который перед ним. Как исправить?

```
<style type="text/css">
.upload-files__container{margin-bottom:14px;}
.upload-file__progres{min-width:0;height:21px;transition:all 0.9s ease;background-color: orange;text-align:center;}
.upload-file__block{width:240px;height:21px;background-color:#DDD;width: 100%;margin-bottom:14px;}
</style>
<div id="upload-files__container">
    
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

var number=0;

function upload(file) {
  number  = ++number;
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  div.className='upload-file__wrap';
  div.innerHTML = '<div id="upload-file__block_'+number+'" class="upload-file__block"><div id="upload-file__progress_'+number+'" class="upload-file__progres"></div></div>';
  document.getElementById('upload-files__container').appendChild(div);
  ajax.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
    var test = ((event.loaded / event.total) *100).toFixed();
    document.getElementById('upload-file__progress_'+number).style.width = test + '%';
    document.getElementById('upload-file__progress_'+number).innerHTML = test + '%';
    if(test == 100) {
      document.getElementById('upload-file__progress_'+number).innerHTML = '';
    }
  }
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("userfile", file);
    
  ajax.open("POST", "admin.php?act=upload_photo", true);
  ajax.send(formData);
}
    </script>

    <input type="file" name="" onchange="upload(this.files[0]);">


  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё очень просто объясняется:

```
//var number = 0; - переменная, к которой обращаются для отображения прогресса
//но она меняет своё значение даже в тех функциях, что были вызваны до её изменения
let number = 0;

function upload(file) {
    //number  = ++number; не знаю, зачем так сложно, перенёс в конец
    let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = 'upload-file__wrap';
    div.innerHTML = '<div id="upload-file__block_'+number+'" class="upload-file__block"><div id="upload-file__progress_'+number+'" class="upload-file__progres"></div></div>';
    document.getElementById('upload-files__container').appendChild(div);
    ajax.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
        let test = ((event.loaded / event.total) *100).toFixed();

        //Если бы переменная number была var, то во всех функциях она приняла бы своё последнее значение
        document.getElementById('upload-file__progress_'+number).style.width = test + '%';
        document.getElementById('upload-file__progress_'+number).innerHTML = test + '%';
        if (test == 100) {
            document.getElementById('upload-file__progress_'+number).innerHTML = '';
        }
    };
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("userfile", file);

    ajax.open("POST", "admin.php?act=upload_photo", true);
    ajax.send(formData);
    number++;
}
```

Во всех не отмеченных мною местах исправил `var` на `let` просто так. [Подробнее здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

> let иногда делает код чище при использовании вложенных функций.